# Tomcat server not being recognized

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm currently using Eclipse Mars on OS X to build a PHP based application which requires a web server for a form submission. However, upon attempting to add Tomcat 7.0 as a server, the server list is empty (shown below).[image: Blank Server List]

I've been following several tutorials for setting up and configuring a Tomcat server and each one says to place the extracted Tomcat folder in the Eclipse workspace directory so they'll be detected when adding them in Eclipse. The Apache Tomcat folder is in the workspace directory but it still isn't being detected. I've tried reinstalling Eclipse and deleting any duplicate files but I keep getting the same result. How can I properly set up and configure an Apache Tomcat server in Eclipse Mars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell it about the Tomcat installation using the Server Runtime Environments [preference page](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/twinstprf.html?cp=78_4_0_8_3).

[image]

If Tomcat isn't already a known server type, you might need to install a few more. The [WTP FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F) has instructions.

All of those tutorials are wrong. You do want to download a copy of Tomcat from Apache so it has the expected layout when Eclipse looks for the jars needed to launch it, but there's no reason to actually put it in the workspace.

Comment: When I went through the preferences panel to check runtime environments there were no apache tomcat servers. There was reference to one in the preference panel but nowhere else. Here's a screen shot of it: http://puu.sh/kzl5y/2578516ba7.png

Comment: You need to install the `JST Server Adapters Extensions` as mentioned in the FAQ to which I linked. Updating to Mars.1 also should not hurt.

Comment: My apologies, I had forgotten to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Eclipse neon and I faced the same problem and the answer was available in a question **Apache Tomcat Not Showing in Eclipse Server Runtime Environments** in the same site already posted

Of the Available Answers the below steps Worked for me:

1.Help-->Eclipse Marketplace

2.Type Tomcat in search box and choose the Option JST Server Adapters(Apache Tomcat,...) and click on Install

3.Then complete the Simple installation steps and after installation Eclipse prompts for a restart accept and then you can see the Target Run time updated with Tomcat server

Note:I am using Windows

Comment: sorry I have mentioned as Eclipse neon as I am using neon